# How to use group-by in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My data-frame look like this(two columns col1,col2)

```
1 100
2 150
3 170
1 200
```

I want to do group-by col1,

```
pd.DataFrame(combined.groupby('col1').aggregate(np.mean)['col2'])
```

This is returning a data-frame with only one key col2, I, actually, want the output to be like this( dataframe with two columns)

```
col1,mean(col2),
```

could somebody point out what do I have to achive this?

Comment: Try call reset_index()

Comment: `df.groupby('col1', as_index=False)['col2'].mean()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
print df.groupby('col1')['col2'].mean().reset_index()
   col1  col2
0     1   150
1     2   150
2     3   170
```

Solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with paameter `as_index=False` as mentioned [`John Galt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491366/how-to-use-group-by-in-pandas/36491451#comment60591029_36491366):

```
print df.groupby('col1', as_index=False)['col2'].mean()
   col1  col2
0     1   150
1     2   150
2     3   170
```

Solution with [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
print df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).aggregate({'col2':'mean'})
   col1  col2
0     1   150
1     2   150
2     3   170
```

[Aggregation in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation)